# Nissan Hardbody Heavy Duty Rear Leaf Springs

Tags: suspension, nissan

My Heavy Duty truck currently has Regular Duty rear leaf springs. The original springs broke when my dad owned the truck and had it a little over loaded. New Heavy Duty springs were too expensive, and were not available in the junk yards, so he replaced them with Regular Duty leaf springs.

On Regular Hardbody trucks, there are 3 leaves in the rear:

- 2 at 7mm thick, and
- 1 at 13mm thick.

On the Heavy Duty Hardbody truck, there are 4 leaves in the rear:

- 2 at 8mm thick, and
- 2 at 14mm thick.

[image: Picture from the 1994 Service Manual]

I was on Courtesy Parts yesterday looking at new rear leaf springs for my HD truck because no local junk yards and no eBay sellers have had the "HD" rear leaf springs for over a year.

Yikes! New springs are still expensive @ $343.72 for **each side**!

- 1986.5 to 1994 Hardbody trucks call for [Part # 55020-D21003](http://www.courtesyparts.com/55020m-spring-rear-suspension-truck-d21-01/1992-hdvg30e-11/1985-01/1992-fedhdfedwtcalhdcalwtvg30-hdvg3-p-109366.html?cPath=3178_3179_3272_3277&):
  [image: Part # 55020-D21003]
  [Link to Part # 55020-D21003](http://www.courtesyparts.com/hardbody-truck-parts-d21-19865-1994/genuine-nissan-parts/axle-suspension/431-rear-suspension/-c-3178_3179_3272_3277.html)
- 1995 to 1997 Hardbody trucks call for [Part # 55020-D21U002](http://www.courtesyparts.com/55020r-spring-assy-leafrear-truck-hardbody-d21u-1995-12/1994-heavy-duty-30l-cyl-p-219693.html?cPath=5388_5389_5484_5488&):
  [image: Part # 55020-D21U002]
  [Link to Part # 55020-D21U002](http://www.courtesyparts.com/hardbody-truck-parts-d21u-1995-1997/genuine-nissan-parts/axle-suspension/431-rear-suspension/-c-5388_5389_5484_5488.html)

Both were the same price, so what is the difference?

Does the newer version have something that was improved upon? Would it still fit in my 1994?

I'd always thought if I found **any** HD version truck that I would be able to use those rear leaf springs. Now I wonder if I need to pay attention to the year as well.

By the way, if anyone has a pair of rear leaf springs for the Heavy Duty Hardbody truck, **I am interested in them**!

Comment: One trick I have used over the years is to look at aftermarket suppliers. They seem to be much more open and knowledgeable about year to year variations. If you  check several suppliers and the model years overlap, the parts will fit. If they breakdown to separate model years there is a reason for it. In some instances the parts will interchange only if both sides are replaced.

Comment: I can't afford new (OEM or aftermarket), so my only option is to sort this out with parts off of existing vehicles. The aftermarket does not even list the HD version of the D21. These Longbed 3/4-ton and 1-ton models were not common.

Comment: @jp2code Are you planning on needing the HD springs? Or are you adjusting the truck's ride? My question is, why not save the money for new HD, if they are actually what you need? You never know how used, the used ones are.

Comment: I wound up adding some helper springs, but I'd still like to find some old original stuff. I'd rather not spend $600 for new ones on this 20-year old truck if I don't need to.

Comment: Latest pic [HERE](http://i.imgur.com/Rmb3yDD.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through the dealership for their expensive/overpriced components, I was able to get the Heavy Duty 4-leaf packs from **General Springs** for $180/side.

Product Code: 69-149

http://www.generalspringkc.com/Leaf_Springs_Nissan_Pickup_s/1947.htm

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most cities should have a few spring works businesses who can reset your existing leaf springs and add an additional leaf or two for considerably less than buying replacement springs. I suggest looking for a local business who offer such a service and call them for a quote. You'll save more money by taking the springs off the truck yourself and refitting them once they've been reset.

Comment: We've got a 4x4 place in town that will get me aftermarket Rancho Suspension, but they want over twice the cost of the original replacement springs. I have not found any other type of business around here that works on springs. Zip 75601.

Comment: Well I was referring to a steel repair shop, not an aftermarket parts retailer. Most of the repair businesses in your neighborhood should know and use such a workshop nearby. Try calling around and ask them or try somewhere like: [link] (http://www.generalspringkc.com/default.asp)

Comment: I'll look into it and ask around.

Comment: So it is a year later. I went with [these](http://www.generalspringkc.com/product_p/69-149.htm). Pic [here](http://i.imgur.com/Lb6bhMH.jpg). Thanks!